# Drupal 6: Inline swf/flv upload in content

Tags: flash, drupal, drupal-6, wysiwyg, inline

Working on a site where I want site admins to be able to upload swf and/or flv files inline in a content's body together with text, images, etc. I'm currently using the WYSIWYG module (with CKEditor).

Basically, what I need is something like http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_imageupload, but for flash content. I've looked for something similar but without success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWFUpload (http://drupal.org/project/swfupload) seems like just the thing for you. But, it's in beta and has a known security flaw, so use at your own risk

You could also use a combination of the built-in `upload` module and SWFTools, if you want something more stable. Just upload the SWF or FLV file using `upload`, and copy-paste the URL of the uploaded file into the SWFTools text filter.

That is, you'd upload foo.flv, and upload would show http://www.yoursite.com/sites/default/files/foo.flv as the file's URL. Then you would add `<swf file="http://www.yoursite.com/sites/default/files/foo.flv">` into the body of the node.

If you're comfortable editing `node.tpl.php` and are up for something even fancier, you could add a CCK filefield to the content type, and call SWFTools directly from the template file based on whatever is in the filefield.

Comment: i thought about using the inline module, which would also work. Thanks for the help, I dont think there is a better solution to this atm.